# CSS nth-child custom pattern

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a blocked grid for content on a website that follows a pattern like shown below. It is essential that it is completely configured with CSS, no JavaScript!

The Pattern:

> | - - - - | => 1 x 100%
>   | - -|- - | => 2 x 50%
>   | - -|- - | => 2 x 50%
>   | - - - - | => 1 x 100%
>   | - -|- - | => 2 x 50%
>   | - -|- - | => 2 x 50%
>   | - - - - | => 1 x 100%
>   | - -|- - | => 2 x 50%
>   | - -|- - | => 2 x 50%
>   | - - - - | => 1 x 100%

I have worked out that `:nth-child(5n+1)` will successfully allow me to style the large, full-width blocks, but for the rest, it will alternate between `:odd` and `:even` until the next element under `(5n+1)` appears.

Has anyone got any suggestions on how to mark this up as described? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Pls provide a fiddle.

Comment: please provide your html and styles you have tried, also could you not just style your 50% cells and then put the nth-child style after that to override it?

Comment: I seem to have gotten an answer via Twitter and will upload to show what I mean. I just wasn't quick enough to get the code up in the first place :S

Comment: Answer provided: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16647813/979455
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you already have pretty much works anyway. You can simply override the default styles in your `nth-type(5n+1)` dividers by giving all your dividers the same markup. For example:

```
<div class='content'>1</div>
<div class='content'>2</div>
<div class='content'>3</div>
<div class='content'>4</div>
<div class='content'>5</div>
<div class='content'>6</div>
...
```

```
.content {
    width:50%;
    font-weight:bold;
    ...
}
.content:nth-child(5n+1){
    width:100%;            /* Overrides 50% */
    font-weight:normal;    /* Overrides bold */
    ...
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y7VYd/).

Comment: Thanks, James. I was in the process of uploading something quite similar as suggested elsewhere but you were first on here so I guess you get the free cake (figuratively speaking of course). Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this quick fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/Z3Vgt/

`nth-child(3n+1)` seems to do the trick, if I'm understanding you right.

Comment: Thanks Duncan but I need 2 rows of 50% boxes, creating a 2x2 grid in itself. But that solution is headed in the same direction.

Comment: with another div around the 50% divs you can get the layout http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/Z3Vgt/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following tool: **nth Tester from CSS-Tricks**

http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: Thanks @DextrousDave, answer provided: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16647813/979455

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys, although I seem to have been provided the answer via Twitter:
http://jsfiddle.net/AK5WL/1/

CSS

```
div {
    width: 19px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

div:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
    clear: both;
    width: 40px;
    background: green;
}
```

Much appreciated all!

Comment: Alternative answer provided: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16647813/979455
Thanks guys!